# Eloquent Many-To-Many on same model, get relation both ways on loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have Report A, Report B and Report C. Reports B and C are related to Report A. When I'm loading a Report A, it shows related reports Report B and C. But then when I load Report B or Report C, the relationship to Report A is not shown.

This is my model:

```
public function related()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Report::class,
        'reports_related',
        'report_id',
        'related_report_id'
    );
}
```

And this is my pivot table:

```
Schema::create('reports_related', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('report_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('related_report_id')->constrained('reports')->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
});
```

How can I load and show the relationship between reports both ways?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to load the reverse relationship:

```
public function relatedReverse()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Report::class,
        'reports_related',
        'report_id',
        'report_id' // This refers to the report_id on the pivot table
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was aware of this option, but was hoping I could do it without and load relations both way with `related()` only. I assume that's not an option?

Comment: I am not actually sure if there is another option, you can try `$this->belongsToMany(...)->union($this->belongsToMany(<other direction>))` but I have no idea if this would work